# AJAX variables in URL do not appear after XMLHttpRequest.open()

Tags: java, javascript, ajax, jsp, url

I'm making an application in Java EE and want to use Ajax to update something. Only the parameters are not appearing in the URL.

The good URL:
localhost:8080/Weblog/AddComment?commenttext=example&postid=3

This is what appears in browserbar as the URL:
localhost:8080/Weblog/AddComment

Javascript:

```
function doAddComment() {
    var url = "AddComment?commenttext="+newcommentcontent.value+"&postid="+postid.value;
    var req = getXHR();
    req.onreadystatechange = function()  
    { processRequestChange(req); 
      req.open("GET", url, true);
      req.send(null);
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to change the GET to a POST.

```
function doAddComment() {
    var url = "AddComment?commenttext="+newcommentcontent.value+"&postid="+postid.value;
    var req = getXHR();
    req.onreadystatechange = function()  
    { processRequestChange(req); 
      req.open("POST", url, true);
      req.send(null);
    }
}
```

And now it works.

Answer (score 2):

You are making the request with Ajax, not sending the browser to a new page. The browser bar shows the URL of the current page, not the URL of the last HTTP resource requested.

Use [the history API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history) if you want to manipulate the address bar to have a history you can go back and forward through when fetching data via Ajax.

Comment: I'm not sending the browser to a new page because it has to update something on the page it is on.